# Multiple npm tests in one Github action

Tags: github-actions, npm-package

I have 3 repos, A,B and C. A is the parent. In the A repo i have a github action, see below.
Package B and C are in package A.

Is it possible and how can i achive to run npm test for repo B en C **BEFORE** i run the test for repo A?

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
name:  Deploy website on create tag
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Use Node.js 14
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '14'
        registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
        scope: '@xxxxxx'
    - name:  NPM install en build prod
      run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}" > .npmrc
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: npm run test

    - name: Copy public dir to production
      uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
      with:
        host:  ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
        key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
        port: ${{secrets.SSH_PORT}}
        command_timeout: 30s
        source: "./public"
        target: "/var/www/html/"
```

Comment: do you mean you have nested folders that each of them contain some test?

Comment: i have 3 repos, each with a npm package. Before i build en TEST de A repo i want to install and TEST repo B and C before i build en TEST repo A.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a job for each testing step A,B and C [described here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-jobs-in-a-workflow). In the code below B and C are each in their own working-directory (/B and /C) within the repository A.
B and C run in parallel. After BOTH have completed successfully job A is run. (Based on your code, not tested)

```
jobs:
  B:
    name: Do job B
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: 'B' 
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js 14
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '14'
        registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
        scope: '@xxxxxx'
    - name:  NPM install en build prod
      run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}" > .npmrc
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: npm run test

  C:
    name: Do job C
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: 'C'
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js 14
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
          scope: '@xxxxxx'
      - name:  NPM install en build prod
        run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}" > .npmrc
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test

  A:
    name: Do job A
    needs: [B, C]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js 14
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
          scope: '@xxxxxx'
      - name:  NPM install en build prod
        run: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}" > .npmrc
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test
      - name: Copy public dir to production
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
          port: ${{secrets.SSH_PORT}}
          command_timeout: 30s
          source: "./public"
          target: "/var/www/html/"
```

Comment: Working directory can point to node_modules/package/B/package.json to install and do the TEST ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
on:
  push
name:  Deploy website on create tag
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  B
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out my other private repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          repository: 'bbb/bbb'
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name:  NPM install en build prod
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test

  web-deploy:
    name:  C
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out my other private repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          repository: 'ccc/ccc'
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name:  NPM install en build prod
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run test
```

And the rest...